# Xdebug with VSCode for Laravel 10 Sail Ubuntu

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, laravel-sail

Unable to make Xdebug work on Laravel Sail 10.x, to develop an API https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-next, developing in Linux Ubuntu 22.04 with VSCode.

Followed instructions for Sail Xdebug configuration
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#debugging-with-xdebug
but I cannot make it work.

launch.json:

```json
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "hostname": "localhost"
    },
```

`.env` variables:

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug,coverage
#SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=192.168.160.1"
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal"
```

Also tried adding the `client_host` IP address as stated in the documentation
`SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=<host-ip-address>"`

Added the following lines to my php.ini (PHP 8.2):

```ini
[XDebug]
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        ...
        image: sail-8.2/app
       - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
       ...
        environment:
            ...
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
```

Start the debugger VSCode extension PHP Debug, add some breakpoints, nothing happens.

---

**UPDATE:**

`xdebug_info()` output:
php > xdebug_info();

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

__   __   _      _                 
\ \ / /  | |    | |                
 \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _ 
  > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
 / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
/_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
                              __/ |
                             |___/ 

Version => 3.2.0
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

          Enabled Features (through 'XDEBUG_MODE' env variable)          
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers => ✔ enabled
Coverage => ✔ enabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                            Optional Features                            
Compressed File Support => no
Clock Source => clock_gettime
'xdebug://gateway' pseudo-host support => yes
'xdebug://nameserver' pseudo-host support => yes
Systemd Private Temp Directory => not enabled

                              Diagnostic Log                              
[Step Debug] WARN: Could not discover client host through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

                              Step Debugging                              
Debugger is not active

                                   PHP                                   
                           Build Configuration                           
Version (Run Time) => 8.2.6
Version (Compile Time) => 8.2.0
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
                                 Settings                                 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-ldap.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pcov.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/25-swoole.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini


Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.mode (through XDEBUG_MODE) => develop,debug,coverage => develop
xdebug.start_with_request => yes => yes
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.use_compression => 0 => 0
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => host.docker.internal => localhost
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host => On => On
xdebug.client_discovery_header => HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR => HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR
xdebug.idekey => VSCODE => VSCODE
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
```

Comment: First of all, did you correctly write the `pathMappings`? I see it ends with `"${workspaceFolder"` but it should be `"${workspaceFolder}"` (you have a missing `}` at the end). Second, usually the issue is related to IPs, but let me know if fixing that, already makes xdebug works for you

Comment: thanks, corrected the typo in `pathMappings` also added the ip from the command `docker inspect -f {{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}} <container-name>` did `sail restart`. Still nothing

Comment: Did you expose port 9003? I don't see that in your docker-compose.yml. can you place `xdebug_info()` in your code? It will show relevant info. Did you install the xdebug extension in vscode?

Comment: Everytime I do a `sail up` i get this log mesage: `laravel.test_1  | Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).`  or whatever IP I add instead of host.docker.internal

Comment: Use `"hostname": "0.0.0.0"` instead of `localhost` on your VSCode xdebug config

Comment: Wow that worked! why?

Answer (score 2):

It finally worked thanks to the comments by @matiaslauriti

Here is my final settings that worked

**php.ini**

```
[XDebug]
    xdebug.start_with_request = yes
    xdebug.discover_client_host = true
    xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

Only this in the **.env**

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug,coverage
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
         ...
```

**launch.json**

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "hostname": "0.0.0.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on a fresh Laravel 10 install. Weird, but I didn't have a launch.json file. After I've auto-created it by clicking on the debug icon in the left hand menu, worked like charm.